# Issue with Conditional Control Statements in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in java/eclipse so i'm learning some basic stuff rn,

This error appear when i'm tryna to type a numbet with ., so if i put 7, 8, 9 ,10... its going right.

But it go wrong when i'm put numbers with . like 7.1, 8.8

My code

```
package controle;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class If {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Type the average: ");
        double average = input.nextDouble();
        
        if(average >= 7.0)
            System.out.println("approved");
            System.out.println("Congratulations");
        
        input.close();
    }

}
```

[image: This is the error]

i didn't understand what happened, cuz its looks right

Comment: Try typing `7,7` -- locale is a thing. Use `{}` because Java is not Python, and you will always print `Congratulations` (regardless of the value of `average`).

Comment: Your if statement needs {}.  And when reading from the console, don't close the scanner.

Comment: You are not having a problem with Eclipse. You are having a problem with the Java language. Eclipse is just an IDE.